# ¿Por qué mi componente ignora el @RequestParam?

Tags: java, spring, rest

Hola estoy dandole vueltas a lo siguiente:

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class ClientRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getS")
    public String getClients(@RequestParam String s){
        return "hola"+s;
    }
}
```

Pero al hacer una peticion GET con `localhost:8081/getS?s=gato` solo me devuelve `hola`!

Un saludo de antemano

Comment: ¿Estás usando Spring Boot?

Comment: no, solo spring version 4.3.16

Comment: Si dice que la prueba le devuelve "hola", tiene parte funcionando... creo que falla otra cosa

Comment: Sip, es solo que no se cómo pasarle un parámetro porque ignora a @RequestParam

Comment: Como @PabloLozano ya dio la respuesta, hay que aclarar que estas confundiendo librerías estas realizando tus servicios con `JAX-RS` y quieres mezclar con `@RequestParam` que es de spring, el hecho de tener la librería de spring en le proyecto no quiere decir que este configurado para exponer servicios REST, @RequestParam es una anotación cuando spring es quien expone los servios REST.

Comment: Era eso entonces. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estás mezclando dos frameworks:

Usando Spring Web, lo normal sería tener algo así:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ClientRestService {

    @GetMapping("/getS")
    public String getClients(@RequestParam String s){
        return "hola"+s;
    }
}
```

Pero si usas [JAX-RS](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2271), entonces sería algo así:

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class ClientRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/getS")
    public String getClients(@QueryParam("s") String s){
        return "hola"+s;
    }

}
```

Puesto que el request llega correctamente a responderse, asumo que tienes JAX-RS funcionando justo con Spring, pero estás usando `@RequestParam` donde deberías usar `@QueryParam`. Puesto que JAX-RS no reconoce esa anotación, no es capaz de colocar ahí el parámetro recibido.

Comment: fantástico ahora funciona perfectamente!!